# How EC2 (persistent) HDFS and EMR (transient) HDFS communicate

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I've set up a Hadoop cluster on Amazon EC2 with NameNode/DataNode and some other services. My ingestion job brings the data into the EC2 HDFS cluster (let's say `hdfs://ec2-hdfs/`).

Now I'm having a pipeline which runs as a weekly batch. I'm launching a new Amazon EMR cluster for running my computation. Once the processing completes, I will terminate the EMR cluster.

The input for my spark job that needs to run in EMR is in EC2 HDFS (`hdfs://ec2-hdfs/`). How can I access it from the newly created EMR cluster? I believe there should be some option (bootstrap/VPC/subnet) available during the EMR Cluster launch.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to bootstrap the `fs.defaultFS` from `core-site.xml` to point at the Namenode for the persistent cluster whenever the EMR cluster starts, or you could explicitly set `hdfs://namenode:port:/ec2-hdfs` within your code.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Looks like a plausible solution. I'll try it out.